# Can't capture headset button

Tags: sony-xperia-z2, headset-controls

I got a new Z2 yesterday and I've discovered that when I press button on my headset (got 1 button there) it increases the volume. I want it to do more that that so I tried all different apps available but none can even capture the key.

I tried uninstalling them all and the try one at a time but no dice. Any ideas?

Comment: Which headset are you using?

Comment: Very basic headphones on cable with one button